# How can I rewrite a URL and pass on the original URL as a parameter?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm building a site that needs to include a 'check' procedure, to do several initiation tasks for a user's session. Examples include checking whether they're accepting cookies, determining if their IP address grants them specific privileges, etc.

Once the check is complete, I need to redirect the user back to the page they originally requested.

The plan is to use `RewriteCond` and map all URLs to an 'initiator' if the user doesn't have a specific cookie set.

Let's say I want to rewrite all URLs (ultimately, with some conditions, of course) to:

```
/foo?original_url=...
```

Where the `...` is the original URL requested, URL-encoded.

The closest I've got is this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/php/cookie.php$1 [R=301]
```

I can then inspect the original URL, captured in the backreference, via `PATH_INFO`. However, this is pretty messy - I would *much* prefer to pass that value as a URL parameter

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write a php that redirects dynamically?

Comment: Look at the mod_rewrite documentation which will tell you how to catch the URI of the original request. Create a new question if you get stuck

Comment: @ghm1014: Not sure what you mean. How would you handle the redirect from any URL?

Comment: @FuzzyFelt: do you mean beyond the use of `$1` to capture the backreference? Is there a special variable that matches a URL-encoded copy of the original URL?

Answer (score 1):

see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa, which covers this exact use-case.

In short, use:

```
RewriteRule /pages/(.+) /otherpage?page=$1 [QSA,R=301,B]
```

The `B` should re-escape the original path.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't redirect, but rather use the FallbackResource directive, you can then access the original requested URI in the env var REQUEST_URI

```
  FallBackResource /cookie.php
```

This has the additional advantage of avoiding the necessity to do explicit RewriteCond's to avoid other valid resources (images, css, and other things you want to be handled normally.)

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource for details.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help - the URLs I wish to redirect *DO* actually exist. I've updated the question a bit to give some more detail - hopefully, it's less confusing now.

Comment: This was the perfect solution for me. To get all the information after using FallbackResource, use ["domain"=>@$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],"URL"=>$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]. Many sites talk about 'front controllers', but they omit how to get the original URL! Just note that anchors (#example) are omitted by REQUEST_URI because the PHP developers consider that anchors are part of HTML and therefore should be ignored by PHP (they apparently don't consider including anchors as very useful in  'front controllers').